# How to use telnet in Windows Command Prompt?

Tags: telnet, command-line

I type this command in a Windows Command Prompt in XP.

```
telnet microsoft.com 80
```

Connecting to microsoft.com appears and then telnet window opens, but there is nothing inside it.

If I type any command like `GET / HTTP/1.1`, it doesn't appear either.

Are my starting steps correct?

Comment: Might be better suited to be asked in SuperUser...

Comment: i think everything is working as it should - telnet does not echo it's prompt .. just make sure to use the proper commands and encoding ... sending some useless glibberish should prompt some answer though.

Comment: I m sorry, but what does that mean ??

Comment: type "telnet microsoft.com 80", enter, type "GET/HTTP/1.0" (won't show on screen), Then press enter twice. (Don't type quotes) Don't bother though, it's just an error.

Comment: Rephrasing what @user175737 said: type `telnet microsoft.com 80`; hit Enter key bringing you a blank console; type `GET / HTTP/1.0` (won't show on screen); hit Enter key twice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Telnet has no echoing by default. Enter *telnet* in interactive mode (no arguments, just execute *telnet*). Then type *set localecho*. Then *open host port*.

I suggest you to use netcat, easier to use and way more powerful. telnet is obsolete.

Comment: Note that when you see `Connecting To microsoft.com...` it has already connected. I thought I need to wait for the connection to succeed, only to find `Connection to host lost.`.

Answer (score 4):

You're trying to connect to an HTTP server, that's what is on port 80 most of the time. The HTTP protocol requires that the guest start talking first. You may want to read up on HTTP if you want to explore: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol

But connecting to port 80 won't get you a shell, telnet servers usually operate on port 23. But telnet is not really used over the Internet anymore because it's not secure.